# How to take the particular details in one division in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have two property details.

If I click first property contact button `myFunction()` it means I want to take property name `3BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar` and property id `1`.

If I click second property contact button `myFunction()` it means I want to take property name `10BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar` and property id `2`.

How can I do this?

```js
var htmlString='';
htmlString+='<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt"><div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;"><a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=1"></a></div><div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;"><h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px; class=" property_name""="">3BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><p class="parclr">Price</p><h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4></div><div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Sqft</p><h4 class="colrh">56565</h4></div><div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p><h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4></div><div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr"> <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p><h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4></div></div><hr><div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;"><div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "></div><div class="col-sm-3 "><div class="contact" style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Contact</button></div></div></div></div></div>';
htmlString+='<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt"><div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;"><a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=5852408f05dd7b0320e3473d"></a></div><div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;"><h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px; class=" property_name""="">3BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><p class="parclr">Price</p><h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4></div><div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Sqft</p><h4 class="colrh">56565</h4></div><div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p><h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4></div><div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr"> <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p><h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4></div></div><hr><div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;"><div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "></div><div class="col-sm-3 "><div class="contact" style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Contact</button></div></div></div></div></div>';

$('#prop_listing').empty().append(htmlString);




function myFunction(that) {
  name = $(that).closest('.prptylstt').find('.property_name').html();
  console.log(name);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prop_listing"></div>
```

Comment: To bind event, use jQuery `on` method. Then `$(this)` inside it will refer to the element that is clicked. Then use `$(this).closest('.prptylstt').find('.property_name').text()`

Comment: you would better use #id than .class to get the element. because, there may be multiple elements with the same class name...

Comment: Hi  Tusha i tried ur code but i did n't get anything,can you update my fiddle

Comment: Also ID MUST be unique. In this case no need for an ID, use the class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. move the code out of the HTML
2. use a class to access all buttons
3. use UNIQUE IDs or no IDs
4. a div does not have a value but has text() or html()
5. use type=button to not submit the form/page

```js
$(function() {
  $(".prlstbtn").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".prptylstt"),
      name = $list.find(".property_name").text(),
      id = $list.find(".p_id").attr("href").split("id=")[1];
    console.log(id, name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row prptylstt">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    <a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=1"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;">
    <h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px;" class="property_name">3BHK Individual House for SALE in Jayanagar</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="parclr">Price</p>
        <h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Sqft</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">56565</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="contact" style="text-align:center;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prlstbtn">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row prptylstt">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    <a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=2"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;">
    <h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px;" class="property_name">10BHK Individual House for SALE in Jayanagar</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="parclr">Price</p>
        <h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 25.70L</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Sqft</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">56565</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="contact" style="text-align:center;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prlstbtn">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refer which button clicked.In onclick function without declaration `this` not performed.so apply with in the function like this `myfuntion(this)` .Then `this` declare in a variable `that` in **DOM**.

And then apply with `jquery` function of **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and **[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method 
  `closest()` to match the parent of the div and `find()` to match  the inner element respected with clicked button.

```js
function myFunction(that) {

 var name = $(that).closest('.prptylstt').find('.property_name').html();
  var id =/(id=)(\w+)/g.exec($(that).closest('.prptylstt').find('.p_id').attr('href'))
  console.log(name);
  console.log(id[2])

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    <a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=1"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;">
    <h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px;" class="property_name">3BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="parclr">Price</p>
        <h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Sqft</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">56565</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="contact" style="text-align:center;">
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
    <a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=2"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;">
    <h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px;" class="property_name">10BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <p class="parclr">Price</p>
        <h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 25.70L</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Sqft</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">56565</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr">
        <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p>
        <h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="contact" style="text-align:center;">
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**or**
 Try with jquery script like this.It's easy to solve your problem.you can use `$(this)`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-default').click(function(){
      var name = $(this).closest('.prptylstt').find('.property_name').html();
        var id =/(id=)(\w+)/g.exec($(this).closest('.prptylstt').find('.p_id').attr('href'))
  console.log(name);
  console.log(id[2])
    })
    })
```

**Updated answer for upadated Question**

class name of the `property_name` is spell mistake `"="` and both html content are `3BHK` .i was corrected with that. see the below snippet.Its work out with query

```js
var htmlString='';
htmlString+='<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt"><div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;"><a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=1"></a></div><div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;"><h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px; class="property_name">3BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><p class="parclr">Price</p><h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4></div><div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Sqft</p><h4 class="colrh">56565</h4></div><div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p><h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4></div><div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr"> <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p><h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4></div></div><hr><div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;"><div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "></div><div class="col-sm-3 "><div class="contact" style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" >Contact</button></div></div></div></div></div>';
htmlString+='<div class="row prptylstt" id="prptylstt"><div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;"><a class="p_id" href="propertydetails.php?id=5852408f05dd7b0320e3473d"></a></div><div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-left:20px;"><h4 style="color:#000;padding-top:12px; class=" property_name">10BHK Individual House for SELL in Jayanagar</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><p class="parclr">Price</p><h4 class="colrh"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 22.70L</h4></div><div class="col-sm-2 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Sqft</p><h4 class="colrh">56565</h4></div><div class="col-sm-4 divbrdr"><p class="parclr">Avaliable From</p><h4 class="colrh">2016-12-16</h4></div><div class="col-sm-3 divbrdr"> <p class="parclr">PostedBy</p><h4 class="colrh">Agent</h4></div></div><hr><div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px;"><div class="col-sm-3"><a class="par" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Quick View</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "> <a class="par"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shortlist</a></div><div class="col-sm-3 "></div><div class="col-sm-3 "><div class="contact" style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default" id="prlstbtn" >Contact</button></div></div></div></div></div>';

$('#prop_listing').empty().append(htmlString);
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
  name = $(this).closest('.prptylstt').find('h4').eq(0).html();
  console.log(name);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prop_listing"></div>
```

Comment: This was already mentioned in a comment. At least show how to move myFunction from being inline to be unobtrusive

Comment: @subikshanM see my upadted answer